# Apache Spark - Scala - ReduceByKey - with keys repeating up to twice only

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given the following RDD:

```
val vectors = RDD [String, Int] = ((k1,v1),(k1,v2),(k2,v3),...)
```

where keys appear either twice (k1) or once (k2), never more than that. I want to get:

```
val uniqVectors = RDD[String, Int] = ((k1, v1*v2), (k2, v3), ...)
```

One approach is to use reduceByKey:

```
val uniqVectors = vectors.reduceByKey((a,b) => a*b)
```

However, it's too slow for arrays with 7B elements. 
Is there any faster approach on this specific case?

Comment: Well... Its not slow... its taking time because of 7B elements.

Comment: Yes! I understand. But consider I'm working on a machine with 2kgb ram and 50 cores. Besides, I'm looking for faster solution on this specific case where kies are not repeated more than once.

Comment: Well... the speed of execution does not depend only on the ram but also on the number of CPU cores. Increase the number of executors when scheduling on spark cluster and increase the number of partitions when creating the rdd.

Answer (score 0):

What (probably) takes the time here is shuffling the data: when you want to group two or more records together, they must reside within the same partition, so Spark has to first *shuffle* the records so that all records with same key are in a single partition.

Now, even if each key has two records at most, this shuffle will have to take place, **unless you can somehow guarantee that each key is already contained in a single partition** - for example, if you loaded this RDD from HDFS and you somehow know that each key resides on a single file part to begin with. In that (unlikely) case, you can use `mapPartitions` to perform the grouping yourself on each partition separately, thus saving the shuffle:

```
vectors.mapPartitions( 
  iter => iter.toList.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k, list) => (k, list.map(_._2).reduce(_ * _)) }.iterator, 
  preservesPartitioning = true)
```

None of this is special to the case where the maximum repetition of each key is 2, by the way.